# Launched Failed.Binary not found in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse and I get this error whenever I hit the button run: Launched Failed.Binary not found.

What should I do? Please if you can explain step by step.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start eclipse the same as you would any other program,

generate a 'project'.

add files to the project,

then clicking run will trigger a compile of all the files, which creates the object files. then a link of all the object files (and needed libraries) to produce an executable, then it tries to run that executable.

I.E. run does nothing useful until the project is fully created and will have plenty of failures until the compiles have no errors and the link has no errors